# Sync or import .ics calendar to Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

On Ubuntu Phone, I have the "Calendar" app from "Ubuntu Core App Developers".

How can I **sync** an .ics calendar between Thunderbird/Lightning and the app, "Calendar"?

How can I **import** an .ics calendar file to the app, "Calendar"?

Comment: If you are considering using owncloud as calDav server, you can try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/606020/how-to-sync-contacts-and-the-calendar-on-ubuntu-touch-with-owncloud

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you must have a google account or a caldav server to sync Calendar with Ubuntu Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Hello (It is late for an answer, I know),

To **import** your calendar on Ubuntu Touch just follow this step:

- Rename your calendar .ics file as **calendar.ics**
- Put this file in `$HOME/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/` **on Ubuntu Touch** (*you may need ssh or the Ubuntu Terminal*)
- Then, reboot your phone

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar Core App doesn't support external calendars yet. But the app (at least the back end) uses SyncEvolution. It can import ics/iCalendar files:

```
syncevolution --import calendar.ics backend=evolution-calendar database=system-calendar
```

SyncEvolution itself does not support subscribing, but you can setup a cron job that fetches the file in question with wget (any public ics calendar) or you could use rsync/scp/sftp/whatever (for syncing between private devices).
Two examples below, but beware: I've not tested them, yet.

```
$ wget -O https://example.org/public-ical.ics | syncevolution --import - backend=evolution-calendar database=system-calendar
$ scp user@myotherdevice:ical-in-home.ics myotherdevice.ics &&
 syncevolution --import - backend=evolution-calendar database=system-calendar &&
 rm myotherdevice.ics
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that currently only Google calendars can be added to the core calendar app. I have logged a question about this on here and even logged a bug report in Launchpad.

[Adding a non-Google calendar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796348/adding-a-non-google-calendar)