# How to sync contacts and the calendar on Ubuntu Touch with OwnCloud

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, evolution, owncloud-server

How do I synchronize contacts and calendars from OwnCloud with the Ubuntu phone?

Answer (score 10):

The Ubuntu phone uses the evolution data server and the data can be synchronized using `syncevolution`.

1. Open an ssh-connection to your Ubuntu Phone (I'm using the Ubuntu-SDK for this purpose)
2. Then execute

   ```
   syncevolution --configure --keyring=no --template webdav username=- password='OCPASSWORD' syncurl="YOURSERVER.COM/owncloud" target-config@owncloud
   ```

   - everything that's written in capitals needs to be replaced with your custom owncloud parameters.
   - if you are using a self-signed certificate you would download it from the server, save it locally and tell syncevolution where to find it `SSLServerCertificates="/home/phablet/YOURCERTIFICATE.crt"`. You can place this command just after the URL parameter.
   - if the above doesn't work, you could use this unsecure alternative `SSLVerifyServer="0"`
3. Now tell syncevolution the information about the phone

   ```
   syncevolution --configure --template SyncEvolution_Client sync=none syncURL=local://@owncloud username= password= owncloud
   ```
4. and the specific parameters for the calendar

   ```
   syncevolution --configure --template webdav database=https://YOURSERVER.COM/owncloud/remote.php/caldav/calendars/OCUSER/personal backend=caldav target-config@owncloud calendar
   ```

   The database path, can be found in the owncloud web frontend by clicking the chain symbol.
5. now

   ```
   syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=calendar database=personal owncloud calendar
   ```
6. and finally start the synchronization

   ```
   syncevolution --sync slow owncloud calendar
   ```

---

For synchronizing the contacts you would just need to add this steps:

8. ```
   syncevolution --configure --template webdav database=https://YOURSERVER.COM/owncloud/remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/OCUSER/contacts backend=carddav target-config@owncloud contacts
   ```

   you can again get the right path from the web frontend
9. ```
   syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=contacts database=personal owncloud contacts
   ```

   database is the name of the address book on your device
10. now run

    ```
    syncevolution --sync slow owncloud contacts
    ```

Comment: My question about adding a self signed certificate is found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/601195/how-can-i-add-a-ca-at-an-ubuntu-phone/603064#603064

Comment: Nice. I will add some information in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/Synchronize-evolution-data-with-caldav-cardav-server

Comment: You can find a bash script to add owncloud contact & calendar, and setup a cronjob to sync on your phone : [ubuntu-touch-add-contact-list-and-calendars](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616081/ubuntu-touch-add-contact-list-and-calendars/664834#664834)

Comment: And if anything goes wrong? how can I delete the config?

Comment: This didn't work for me until I used my OCUSER in step 2 (username=OCUSER) and I dropped the word "personal" in steps 5 and 9 (syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=calendar database= owncloud calendar).

Comment: Step 8 had to be (for me): `syncevolution --configure --template webdav database=https://YOURSERVER.COM/owncloud/remote.php/dav/addressbooks/users/OCUSER/contacts backend=carddav target-config@owncloud contacts`

Comment: Currently, I have not been able to sync my contacts automatically. However, my calendar is a different issue, it performs the sync automatically without me having to do anything. I have one Google calendar and 2 tablets and 2 phones connected. When I make a change to the calendar on one device, the other three get the update within a matter of minutes. I have not done any of the configuration above. It does it automatically.