# Adding a non-Google calendar

Tags: ubuntu-touch, calendar

I have just signed up for a fruux.com calendar and contacts account. However, when I try to add these details to my tablet's Calendar app I am unable to.

All I can add is a Google account. How can I add a non-Google account to my Calender app?

Comment: Currently I do not think you can as I have tried to and was uncesaful. It is like adding an accout that is not a Google account in Settings. Not sure if this has been raises before, but could be one for Launchpad.

Comment: I have raised this as a bug in launchpad.

Comment: Bug #1603062 has been logged.

Comment: There's currently a 80$ Bounty on this on Bountysource: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/30551831-no-caldav-and-icalendar-support

Comment: That is good. Now we have this issue raised in a few places, hopefully the next build (or following) will have the option to use a none Google calendar. I personally like the idea of Ubuntu Touch as I want to move away from Google as much as I can.

Comment: Fruux supports caldav. You can add any caldav account through [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution).

Comment: I have already signed up for a Fruux account. However, unable to add it to Touch.

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered in  [How to sync contacts and the calendar on Ubuntu Touch with OwnCloud](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606020/how-to-sync-contacts-and-the-calendar-on-ubuntu-touch-with-owncloud).
I managed to sync from radicale server but had to turn off SSL. No idea of how to make it work with SSL certificate or where to copy it.
I am trying with Horde, but the same SSL issue.
Even, ubuntu touch calendar GUI has an option to add owncloud calendars without the need of using the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. That is my issue that within the touch calendar there is no way to add.

Comment: Searching in the web you will find lot of people that has success in fetching data for other calendar servers through the terminal commands. Tell us if you get it. BTW, although I do not know what to do with my radicale SSL certificate, with Horde (university's server) I have not ithe certificate and do not know how it can be properly "installed" through the terminal commands.